# Unity: How to convert position between parent and child transform in a correct way?

Tags: unity

(Unity coord system seems to be extremely confusing and documentation is useless.)
**The initial questions seems ambiguous, so let me make some clear questions about Transform and RectTransform (which surely have a definitive answer).**

1. What is the relationship between Transform and RectTransform? Do they modify each other?
   **Does Transform modify RectTransform data?** Apparently no.
   **Does RectTransform modify parent or child Transform data?** I thought no.
   **Does RectTransform modify same-level Transform (.transform)  data?** I thought yes.
2. RectTransform.GetRectInParentSpace() is implemented in CIL(.NET).
   It does not take same-level Transform's rotation/scale/full matrix into account.
   **Does it mean that same-level Transform is fully managed by RectTransform and may not have anything more than translation?**
3. GetRectInParentSpace() is internal (and there is not used), **what is the official way to get the actual bound of a RectTranfrom?**
4. RectTranfrom has lots of parameter and most are not implemented in CIL.
   **rect; anchorMin; anchorMax; anchoredPosition; sizeDelta; pivot;**
   **Which of them are independent and what are the math formulas for them?**

```
        internal Rect GetRectInParentSpace()
        {
            Rect rect = this.rect;
            Vector2 vector = this.offsetMin + Vector2.Scale(this.pivot, rect.size);
            if (base.transform.parent)
            {
                RectTransform component = base.transform.parent.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
                if (component)
                {
                    vector += Vector2.Scale(this.anchorMin, component.rect.size);
                }
            }
            rect.x += vector.x;
            rect.y += vector.y;
            return rect;
        }
```

====Initial questions====

For example, I want to implement a simple drag in 2D UI.

1. So I want to handle the drag in ancestor coord, and then convert back to dragging object.
   The problem is, what positional data should I get/set from the dragging object?

```
// If using anchorPosition is wrong, then what should I use?
startObjectPositionInAncestor = dragRectT.anchorPosition;
...
// The position in ancestor works as expected.
RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(ancestorRectT, screenInputPoint, canvas.worldCamera, out Vector2 pointInAncestor);
var newPositionInAncestor = (pointInAncestor - startPointInAncestor) + startObjectPositionInAncestor;
// Now how to map the position to child object under drag?
// Below does not work: position is flickering.
// dragRectT.anchorPosition = dragRectT.InverseTransformPoint(ancestorRectT.TransformPoint(newPositionInAncestor)));
dragRectT.anchorPosition = ???
// Or using anchorPosition is wrong, then what should I use?
```

> Update
> Set RectTransform.anchoredPosition seems to modify same-level Transform (.transform) and thus cannot be used by coord conversion during drag.
> I think parent transform can be used.
> But the question remains:
> What should I use: anchoredPosition, localPosition, or something else?
>
> (The 2nd question was a mistake so I removed it. The root cause is same as 1st: position went wild when I used anchoredPosition + same-level transform, and I made wrong guess from it.)

Note:
I am modding so I cannot reproduce it in editor or provide screenshot of object properties in editor.

Comment: Is there a reason you use the anchorPosition and not just the transform.position?

Comment: It's difficult to understand the issue from just these small snippets. Can you show the wider context this code fits into, and describe in more detail how it's behaviour differs from what you want? Even if you're working on a mod, you can still create a new scene in a new Unity project to illustrate the problem, and provide a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example we can use to test potential answers to be sure they'll work for you.

Comment: Perhaps you should use the Unity Editor to figure out how to do what you want to do and then copy your solution into the mod.

Comment: @Zibelas I just don't know what to use because unity doc is so poor. (Game code used anchorPosition so I copied it) If transform.position is the absolute reference point that does not change due to RectTransform's parameters (anchor etc.), then I can/should use it.

Comment: The problem is, I have no idea how is RectTransform's parameter calculated together. @DMGregory If I am able to reproduce the problem in editor, then it mostly like that I almost understood the problem. (For example, I saw some RectTransform parameters, but I could neither understand it, and do not know how to regenerate it in Editor, as Editor params are different from runtime data.)

Comment: Unity's documentation is mostly pretty solid. Which part are you confused by?

Comment: @Kevin All of the parameters of RectTransform should have math formula documented. Relationship between Transform/RectTransform should be fully explained.